# AngularJS not working with a regular form

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

The code below is suppose to send the user data to a python script. However, the submit button nor the form does not do anything. 
I have tested the python script without AngularJS and it works perfectly fine.

After a bit testing I have found that if I just remove ng-app the submit button would work but not any of the AngularJS Materials (outside the md-card). So I suspect that ng-app maybe doing it.

I have also trying moving the ng-app around the script hoping for something but nothing changed.

Unfortunately I cannot post the python script since the python script is not my work.

I split the script into 2 parts in case it might be easier to read that way

## Javascript, CSS, and Stuff

```
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset = "UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.0.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Fira+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

  <style>
    /*Centers the main Login box*/
  .completeCard
  {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        width: 50%;
    }

      /*Centers the introduction Text*/
      .introText
  {
        text-align: center; 
    font-family: 'Fira Sans', sans-serif;       
      }

      /*modifies the checkbox*/
      .checkbox
  {
        padding-top: 1em;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    }

  /*Centers the headline*/
      .md-headline
  {
      text-align: center;
    }

</style>

  <script language="javascript">
     var app = angular.module('signIn',['ngMaterial']);
     app.controller('inputController', inputController);

     function inputController ($scope,$mdDialog) 
     {
       $scope.project = {
          comments: 'Comments',    
       };

       //Creates a pop up when the user clicks the submit button
      $scope.showAlert = function(ev) 
      {
           $mdDialog.show
           (
              $mdDialog.alert()
                 .parent(angular.element(document.querySelector('#dialogContainer')))
                 .clickOutsideToClose(true)
                 //title of the pop up alert box
                 .title('Thank You!')
                 //The dialog that comes up on the alert box
                 .textContent("Test")
                 .ariaLabel('Thank You')
                 //The close button for the alert box
                 .ok('Ok!')
                 .targetEvent(ev)
           );
        };           
     }                 
  </script>
```

## Body Part

```
    <body ng-app="signIn" ng-controller="inputController">
     <div id="title" class="introText">
        <h1> Sign-In </h1>
     </div>


  <div id="inputContainer" class="completeCard" ng-controller="inputController as ctrl" ng-cloak>
      <md-content layout-padding>
        <md-card>
          <md-card-title>
            <md-card-title-text>
              <span class="md-headline">Login</span>

                    <form method="post" name="projectForm">  
                <md-input-container>
                  <label>Secret Key</label>
                  <input required name="secret" type = "text" ng-model="project.secret" value="$${secret}">
                  <md-tooltip>Written on a board or ask an representative</md-tooltip>
                  <div ng-messages ="projectForm.secret.$error">
                    <div ng-message = "required"> This is required </div>
                  </div>
                </md-input-container>
                <md-input-container class="md-block">
                  <label>Name</label>
                  <md-tooltip>First and Last Name</md-tooltip>                  
                  <input required name="name" type="text" ng-model="project.name" value="$${name}">
                  <div ng-messages="projectForm.name.$error">
                    <div ng-message="required">This is required.</div>
                  </div>
                </md-input-container>

                <md-input-container class="md-block">
                  <label>Email</label>
                  <input required type="email" name="email" ng-model="project.userEmail"
                   minlength="5" maxlength="100" ng-pattern="/^.+@.+\..+$/" /  value = "$${email}">
                  <md-tooltip>Please use your School Email</md-tooltip>
                  <div ng-messages="projectForm.email.$error" role="alert">
                   <div ng-message-exp="['required', 'minlength', 'maxlength', 'pattern']">
                    Your email must be between 5 and 100 characters long and should be a valid email address.
                   </div>
                  </div> 
                </md-input-container>  

                <md-input-container-select>
                  <md-tooltip>All Majors are in Alphabetical Order</md-tooltip>
                    <div>
                    <md-select ng-model="major" placeholder="Major" class="md-no-underline" name="major" value"$${major}">
                      <md-option value="n/a">Not a Student</md-option>
                      <md-option value="major1">Major 1</md-option>
                      <md-option value="major2">Major 2</md-option>
                    </md-select>
                  </div>
                </md-input-container-select> 

               <md-checkbox class="green" name = "add_s" value=$${sec_checked}>
                 Join Mailing List
               </md-checkbox>

                    <!-- <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="end center"> -->
              <br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                <div style="color:red; font-size:20pt"> $${response}</div>
                </br>
                <!-- <md-button type="submit" class="submitButton" ng-click="showAlert($event)">Submit</md-button> -->
              <!-- </md-card-actions> --> 
              </form>
            </md-card-title-text>
            <md-card-title-media>
             <div class="md-media-lg card-media"></div>
            </md-card-title-media>
         </md-card-title>
       </md-card>
     </md-content>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

## Edit

Here's what works without the AngularJS Materials

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Sign-in</title>
  </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Sign-in</h1>
    <form method="post">
      Secret key: <input type="text" name="secret" value="$${secret}"/><br/>
      Name: <input type="text" name="name" value="$${name}"/><br/>
      Email: <input type="text" name="email" value="$${email}"/><br/>
      Major: <input type="text" name="major" value="$${major}"/><br/>
      <span style='width:300pt; float:left'>Add me to the CCDC team!</span>
          <input type="checkbox" name="add_c" $${ccdc_checked}/><br/>
      <span style='width:300pt; float:left'>Add me to the Cyber Defense Team mailing list!</span>
          <input type="checkbox" name="add_d" $${cdt_checked}/><br/>
      <span style='width:300pt; float:left'>Add me to the SIG-Sec mailing list!</span>
          <input type="checkbox" name="add_s" $${sec_checked}/><br/>

      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/><br/>
      <div style="color:red; font-size:20pt">$${response}</div> <br/>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't seem to bind the `submit` input with `showAlert` or am I missing something here ?

Comment: You have the button commented out.

Comment: @AdrianBrand I commented out the AngularJS Materials button since it wasn't working and replaced it with a regular ol' submit button hoping it would work....it didn't

Comment: @Searching I commented out the button that was connected to `showAlert`, it is the same button I commented out that Adrian Brand was talking about

Comment: OK if you do not need the `showAlert` then it's safe to check if you have a `form` html tag for the md-card as @AdrianBrand pointed out for the submit to actually post back to your php action

Comment: @Searching The `alert` function does not communicate to anything but itself (at least it's not intended to). I made it just so I can have a pretty popup box when the user clicks on submit. Changing to `type=button` didn't work either.

Comment: Ya.. i realized that was not your intention and added a new comment. When you click on submit does it even do anything ? Like anything in the dev console ? network tab, console tab ...

Comment: @Searching Not that anything I see. There is a `Use of getUserData() or setUserData() is deprecated. Use WeakMap or element.dataset instead.` when the page loads. I don't think that has anything to do with the button. But nothing happens when I press the button

Comment: Hmmm..If you do not see any network activity then noting is posting to you server. Which means that the submit is not working and that is possibly because of no `form` html tag around the html as per the question. I suggest verifying/pasting the entire html of that page if possible. And do you really need `ng-controller="inputController as ctrl"` declared twice ?

Comment: I removed `ng-controller="inputController as ctrl"` but nothing happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You form needs an action

```
<form method="post" name="projectForm" action="urlOfYourPythonScript">
```

or you will need to do a http post inside your click handler.

Comment: The python scripts are a self-contained web sever

Comment: The previous script without AngularJS Materials worked fine without an action

Comment: @SirSheep you are missing the point here. The server scripts are intact and good, no comments about it. The point is there is no `action` on the html `form` for the submit to work. It's like having a post card without a To address. Nothing wrong with the contents of the post card, the sender or the receiver. It  just doesn't know where to go. Read this for further info on `form` https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.3.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up adding `action=""`. But why does it require an `action`? The one previously made did not require one.